# How to add octopus deploy created .cer file to new Azure portal?

Tags: azure, octopus-deploy

How do I add octopus deploy created .cer file to new Azure portal(https://portal.azure.com)? 
I can do it in old Azure portal(https://manage.windowsazure.com) in before, but MS didn't allow my account to access the old Azure portal.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, the new management portal (and a new management model ARM) does not use certificates, instead of that it uses Service Principals ([link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/7473259-management-certificates)). There is the pane called Management Certificates, but it will forward you to the [that page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal/).

There are Octopus-written references that you may use for making it work:
http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Creating+an+Azure+Management+Certificate+Account

http://docs.octopusdeploy.com/display/OD/Deploy+using+an+Azure+Resource+Group+Template